# Get values in Firebase Realtime Database with specific value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here's the structure of my Firebase for my chat-app.

[image]

What I want to do is retrieve all results for `name` equalling `"Trillian"`. How would I go about that in Swift?

For reference, the overall structure is:

```
chatapp/
    chats/
         {$key}/
               name (string)
               sender_id (string)
               text (string)
```

Thanks :)

Comment: which database are you using firestore or realTime?

Comment: Using real-time, thanks :)

Comment: you should used Query like this may be it will work for you. i have not test it

` let messageQuery = ref.child("chatapp").child("chats").child("key").child("name").queryEqualToValue("Trillian")`

Comment: See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541716/querying-firebase-with-swift-3-0, which shows it'd be something like: `Database.database().reference().child("chats").queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue : "Trillian")`